# pandas dataframe merge avoid suffics

Tags: python, pandas

I have the two data frme, the two df's have the same column , during inner join it become column1_x,column1_y,column2_x,column2_y

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7],
                    'column1': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'],
                    'column2': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [5, 6, 7],
                    'column1': ['B', 'B', 'B'],
                    'column2': ['B', 'B', 'B']})
```

df1

```
id  column1 column2
1   A   A
2   A   A
3   A   A
5   A   A
6   A   A
7   A   A
```

df2

```
id  column1 column2
5   B   B
6   B   B
7   B   B
```

i need output like this:

Result

```
id  column1 column2
1   A   A
2   A   A
3   A   A
4   A   A
5   B   B
6   B   B
7   B   B
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`combine_first()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) method in pandas.

Your example :

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7],
                    'column1': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'],
                    'column2': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [5, 6, 7],
                    'column1': ['B', 'B', 'B'],
                    'column2': ['B', 'B', 'B']})

combined = df2.set_index('id').combine_first(df1.set_index('id')).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

So idea is to combine two dataframe and drop duplicates row on the basis of `column id` with priority is to keep the last duplicate.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7],
                    'column1': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'],
                    'column2': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [5, 6, 7],
                    'column1': ['B', 'B', 'B'],
                    'column2': ['B', 'B', 'B']})

pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates(subset='id', keep='last')
```

So concatenate `df1` and `df2` and then drop the last duplicates on the basis of `column id`